# How to use a different layout for my component?

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

My custom component seems to be using the site default template index.php at the moment.

How can I get it to use a custom layout just for the component? I don't want to create an entirely new template, just a new layout file which can use the template's CSS and other assets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is exactly what you are talking about - this is about the component layout. If you are talking about your entire Joomla template, this is not the answer.

Either you create a new view (but then you might need a new model, too) or you use the layout functionality. I described it [here](http://violetfortytwo.blogspot.de/2012/11/joomla-25-multiple-views-one-model.html) when I figured it out. In a nutshell: Go to your `views/yourview/tmpl` folder and create a new file `newlayout.php`. You'll be able to use it like this:

`index.php&option=com_yourcomponent&view=yourview&layout=newlayout`.